# Delete all versions of paper_trail when delting a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paper-trail-gem

I'm using the paper_trail gem for a blogging system to store versions of the article.  However I don't need to keep any version of an article after it has been destroyed.

How can I delete all versions of a model instance when it's destroyed?  I only see in the documentation a way to delete versions globally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
before_destroy do
  self.versions.destroy_all
end
```

By default `has_paper_trail` creates `has_many :versions` association. So you can easily destroy all of them. But make sure in your model you have this :

```
 has_paper_trail on: [:create, :update]  #because you dont want to keep record for destroy event.
```

Comment: Why do you do self.versions.collect(&:destroy) instead of self.versions.destroy_all ?

Comment: Changed according to your suggestion :)

Comment: Oh, okay!  I didn't actually know if there was a difference.

Comment: i'm guessing you could use `delete_all` instead since you I doubt you would want callbacks or validations running

Comment: wouldn't you want to use after_destroy incase the destroy fails you don't prematurely delete data?